# What statistical test is needed here?

Tags: r, statistical-learning

I'm trying to find which type of statistical test I need for the study below (inputting into SPSS). I was thinking it could be repeated measures ANOVA or numerous paired t-tests??? Thoughts please...

Title: A study into the effects of acute creatine supplement on cognitive function of sleep deprived subjects.

- 1 Group (n=11)
- 4 weeks of testing
- 3 cognition tests
- 2 supplements: Creatine & Placebo
- 2 conditions: Sleep deprived and non-sleep deprived
- **Week 1**: Non-sleep deprived & Creatine (3 cognitive tests)
- **Week 2**: Non-sleep deprived & Placebo (3 cognitive tests)
- **Week 3**: Sleep deprived & Creatine (3 cognitive tests)
- **Week 4**: Sleep deprived & Placebo (3 cognitive tests)

Comment: Were there any time lapses between weeks? Or are the 4 weeks consecutive?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight the 4 tests were done over 2 months, and it wasn't necessary for certain time lapses between the weeks (no effecting dominators)

Answer (score 4):

A within-subjects ANOVA is preferred over paired t-tests both because it protects against family-wise alpha inflation and allows you to analyze the potential interactive effects of your two factors.

However ,your sample size is also quite small. I would look carefully to ensure that the  [ANOVA assumptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Assumptions_of_ANOVA) are met. If not, you might consider a Friedman Test.

T-tests (parametric) or Wilcoxon signed-rank tests (non-parametric) would have to follow a significant omnibus test to determine precisely where the differences lie.